# Miragejs seeds function not called

Tags: javascript, reactjs, miragejs

I'm trying to set-up a miragejs server, but for some reason, the `seeds` function is not called. The other server function, `routes`, is called and the routes are mapped correctly.

```js
export default function makeServer({ environment = 'test' } = {}) {
  return new Server({
    environment,

    models: {
      user: Model,
      diary: Model,
    },

    seeds(server) {
      debugger; // not hit
      seedUsers(server);
      seedDiaries(server);
    },

    routes() {
      debugger; // hit
      this.namespace = 'api';
      this.get('/users', (schema) => schema.users.all());
      this.get('/diaries', (schema) => {
        debugger; // hit
        schema.diaries.all();
      });
    },
  });
}
```

I've tried copy-pasting the provided [example](https://miragejs.com/quickstarts/react/develop-an-app/), but the `seeds` method is still not called.

The miragejs package is installed as a dev package and the used version is 0.1.40. The `makeServer` function is called in the index.jsx file like this:

```js
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  makeServer();
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
      <App />
    </ConnectedRouter>
  </Provider>,
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
  document.getElementById('root'),
);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Changing the `makeServer` function's `environment` parameter to `development` or removing it entirely (it defaults to `development`) solves the issue. It seems that when using the `test` environment, the `seeds` method is ignored ([source](https://miragejs.com/docs/testing/application-tests/#the-test-environment)).

Comment: Indeed https://miragejs.com/docs/main-concepts/factories/#in-testing